# How can I split a text from a parenthesis in a CSV, and create another column with it

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm completely new to the Python world, so I've been struggling with this issue for a couple days now. I thank you guys in advance.

I have been trying to separate a single Row and column text in three diferente ones. To explain myself better, here's where I am.

So this is my pandas dataframe from a csv:

In[2]:

```
df = pd.read_csv('raw_csv/consejo_judicatura_guerrero.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ["institution"]
df
```

Out[2]:

```
       institution 
0      1.1.2. Consejo Nacional de Ciencias (CNCOO00012)
```

Then, I try first to separate the **1.1.2.** in a new column called **number**, which I kind of nailed it:

In[3]:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['institution'].str.split('. ',1).tolist(),columns=['number', 'institution'])
```

Out[3]:

```
       number institution 
0      1.1.2. Consejo Nacional de Ciencias (CNCOO00012)
```

Finally, trying to split the **(CNCOO00012)** in a new column called **unit_id** I get the following:

In[4]:

```
new_df['institution'] = pd.DataFrame(new_df['institution'].str.split('(').tolist(),columns=['institution', 'unit_id'])
```

Out[4]:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-70d13206881c> in <module>
----> 1 new_df['institution'] = pd.DataFrame(new_df['institution'].str.split('(').tolist(),columns=['institution', 'unit_id'])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    472                     if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
    473                         columns = data[0]._fields
--> 474                     arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
    475                     columns = ensure_index(columns)
    476 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    459         return [], []  # columns if columns is not None else []
    460     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 461         return _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
    462     elif isinstance(data[0], abc.Mapping):
    463         return _list_of_dict_to_arrays(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    491     else:
    492         # list of lists
--> 493         content = list(lib.to_object_array(data).T)
    494     # gh-26429 do not raise user-facing AssertionError
    495     try:

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.to_object_array()

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What can I do to successfully achieve this task?

Comment: Does the data in the rows is always consistent i.e. `number `followed by `institution ` followed by `unit_id`?

Comment: This error is because one or some of the entries has ```None``` value in institution column. Try to handle the null values either by removing or filling them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `assign` with `str.split` like below. But format of text should be fixed.

```
df.assign(number = df.institution.str.split().str[0], \
          unit_id = df.institution.str.split().str[-1])
```

Output:

```
                                        institution  number       unit_id
0  1.1.2. Consejo Nacional de Ciencias (CNCOO00012)  1.1.2.  (CNCOO00012)
```

Or If you want to strip `()` from `unit_id` use

```
df.assign(number = df.institution.str.split().str[0], \
          unit_id = df.institution.str.split().str[-1].str.strip('()'))

                                        institution  number     unit_id
0  1.1.2. Consejo Nacional de Ciencias (CNCOO00012)  1.1.2.  CNCOO00012
```

Comment: In this solution the round brackets are not stripped off the unit_id.

Comment: @mac13k Thanks to bring attention. i have update my answer.

Comment: Glad It helps. As you are new here;If you found any answer good for you. you should mark it as a [ANSWER](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) using green tick.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but what about using named capture groups in a regular expression. For example, use the following after you imported your CSV-file:

```
df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'^(?P<number>[\d.]*)\s+(?P<instituion>.*)\s+\((?P<unit_id>[A-Z\d]*)\)$')
```

This would expand your dataframe as such:

```
   number                    instituion     unit_id
0  1.1.2.  Consejo Nacional de Ciencias  CNCOO00012
```

---

About the regular expression's pattern:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `^` - A start string ancor
- `^(?P<number>[\d.]*)` - A named capture group, number, made up of zero or more characters (greedy) in character class of dots and digits.
- `\s+` - One or more spaces.
- `(?P<instituion>.*)` - A named capture group, institution, made up of zero or more characters (greedy) other than new-line.
- `\s+\(` - One or more spaces followed by a literal opening paranthesis.
- `(?P<unit_id>[A-Z\d]*)` - A named capture group, unit_id, made up of zero or more characters (greedy) in character class of uppercase letters and digits.
- `\)$` - Closing paranthesis followed by end of string ancor.

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZliNc0/4)

Comment: thank you for the solution and the explanation. I worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

If your data is tidy enough you can perform all three steps in one command using `pd.Series.str.extract()` which can split a series of strings into columns by regex, ie.:

```
df.institution.str.extract(r'(?P<number>[0-9.]+) (?P<institution>[A-Za-z ]+) \((?P<unit_id>[A-Z0-9]+)')
```

If the missing values cause a problem you can add `dropna()`:

```
df.institution.dropna().str.extract(r'(?P<number>[0-9.]+) (?P<institution>[A-Za-z ]+) \((?P<unit_id>[A-Z0-9]+)')
```

Output:

```
   number                   institution     unit_id
0  1.1.2.  Consejo Nacional de Ciencias  CNCOO00012
```